# The study of $\operatorname{Map}(G,\;M)$ in general, when $G$ is not $S^1$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

The loop space $\operatorname{Map}(S^1,\;M)$ (with your favorite smoothness and Sobolev conditions) has been heavily studied with its rich structures, such as the symplectic structure.

I wonder if there are some nice results about $\operatorname{Map}(G,\;M)$ when $G$ is not $S^1$. Thank you.

edit: Here by $G$ I mean a compact Lie group, and by $M$ I mean a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: What is $G$ instead? A compact Lie group?

Comment: If you want the loop space to be something like a group, you need $G$ to be something like a co-group, i. e. a nice map $G\to G\vee G$. But then again, this probably has nothing to do with what you want...

Comment: If you want to involve a Lie group then it's a little more usual to study Map(X,G) where X is a compact manifold and G is a Lie group.  Taking this line, you should look at _Loop Groups_ by Pressley and Segal as they discuss this generalisation a little.  Mapping out of a Lie group isn't anything particularly special (and there aren't many cogroups in smooth manifolds ...), but people have studied mapping out of other manifolds than just S^1; for example, there's considerable work on mapping out of surfaces.

Comment: Checkout Alexander Braverman's stuff titled "Pursuing the double affine Grassmannian". There are maybe 3 papers and they strike me very much as an algebraic take on this question. I think they are trying to understand the Geometric Satake for loop groups which involves this double affine Grassmannian. 